# Deleting rows from multiples tables at once

Tags: mysql, query, php, mysqli

I have a question about this piece of code I just wrote. I have a problem with the syntax, the first query executes its purpose, the problem is in the second query which does not.

```php
if(isset($_POST['deletecontr'])){
  $dcquery = $_POST['dni']; // This get the ID of the person who I want to delete.
  $catchempr = ("SELECT `empresa` FROM `contratistas` WHERE dni='$dcquery'"); //This catch the name of the company of that person
  $query = ("DELETE FROM `contratistas` WHERE dni='$dcquery'"); // This works fine
  $query2 = ("DELETE FROM `empleados` WHERE empresa='$catchempr'"); This does not.
  mysqli_query($link,$query);
  mysqli_query($link,$query2); 
  echo "La empresa a sido eliminada de la base de datos";
```

I hope you guys can see something that I'm not seeing.

Comment: You should really start with **prepared statements**, your could is vulnerable to sqo injection  $catchempr  is true or false and has not the  result if the select in it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm aware of the SQLi issue, but this actually take data from a form which has a readonly property, It just read the text impressed in the box and make the delete action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You programming mus be complete.

Like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['deletecontr'])){
      $dcquery = $_POST['dni']; // This get the ID of the person who I want to delete.
      if (isset($dcquery)) {          
             if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT `empresa` FROM `contratistas` WHERE dni=?")) {    
                /* bind parameters for markers */
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $dcquery);

                /* execute query */
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
                if($affected_rows > 0 ){
                    /* bind result variables */
                   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $empresa);
                   /* fetch value */
                   mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
                   mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
                   if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "DELETE FROM `contratistas` WHERE dni=?")) {
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $dcquery);
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                        $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)
                        if($affected_rows > 0 ){ 
                            if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "DELETE FROM `empleados` WHERE empresa=?")) {
                                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $empresa);
                                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                                $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)
                                if($affected_rows > 0 ){ 
                                    echo "La empresa a sido eliminada de la base de datos";
                                } else {
                                   echo 'Error Delete empleados<br />';
                                   echo mysqli_error();
                                   mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                                   mysqli_close($dbc);
                                }
                            } else {
                               echo 'Error Delete Empresas<br />';
                               echo mysqli_error();
                               mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                               mysqli_close($dbc);
                            }
                        } else {
                          echo 'Error Occurred<br />';
                          echo mysqli_error();
                          mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                          mysqli_close($dbc);
                        }
                     } else {
                          echo 'Error Occurred<br />';
                          echo mysqli_error();
                          mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                          mysqli_close($dbc);
                     }
            } else {
                  echo 'Error Occurred<br />';
                  echo mysqli_error();
                  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                  mysqli_close($dbc);
             }
        } else {
              echo 'Error Occurred<br />';
              echo mysqli_error();
              mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
              mysqli_close($dbc);
         }
    } else {
    echo 'NO DNI<br />';
    }
}
```

Usually i use PDO and much more object oriented programming.

Even if prepared statementst are not really necessary, you should use them to practise and understand its workings.

As you can see every query is checked, if it does its job and you know how many rows are affected, if you need to check something.

A clear programming helps also when you have to work on it in one or two years or if a update of php or mysql or something it comes to an eroor.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code to this, it'll work:

```
if(isset($_POST['deletecontr'])){
  $dcquery = $_POST['dni']; // This get the ID of the person who I want to delete.
  $catchempr = ("SELECT `empresa` FROM `contratistas` WHERE dni='$dcquery'"); //This catch the name of the company of that person
  $query = ("DELETE FROM `contratistas` WHERE dni='$dcquery'"); // This works fine
  $query2 = ("DELETE FROM `empleados` WHERE empresa in ($catchempr)"); This does not.
  mysqli_query($link,$query);
  mysqli_query($link,$query2); 
  echo "La empresa a sido eliminada de la base de datos";
```

By doing this, I have changed the query from roughly:

```
DELETE FROM `empleados` WHERE empresa='SELECT `empresa` FROM `contratistas` WHERE dni='$dcquery'' -- // ignore the $dcquery part
```

to:

```
DELETE FROM `empleados` WHERE empresa in (SELECT `empresa` FROM `contratistas` WHERE dni='$dcquery')
```

By expanding the query strings you can see that the first query is not valid for a couple of reasons.

I'll also add that this code is susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection) because you are not verifying or filtering the input string `$_POST['deletecontr']`. To mitigate this, use [bind variables/prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply! I tried your way and i get the same result, it only delete the empleados row

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DELETE
FROM contratistas, empleados
WHERE contratistas.dni = $_POST['dni']
  AND empleados.empresa = contratistas.empresa;
```

I.e.

```php
if(isset($_POST['deletecontr'])){
  $dcquery = $_POST['dni'];
  $query = ("DELETE FROM contratistas, empleados WHERE contratistas.dni = '$dcquery AND empleados.empresa = contratistas.empresa;");
  mysqli_query($link,$query);
}
```

Comment: Hey @Akina i get the ```contratistas``` row deleted, but not the ```empleados``` row. Either way, i change the input to take information on ```empresas``` and not ```dni``` so with the same input i can take care of both tables! Thank you!!